# Visual Code Studio won't let me run discord.py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.py

**Code**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.id)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 291, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 245, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\infin\OneDrive\Desktop\Mythrix_Exclusive\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run('TOKEN')
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 295, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000018A6D22BD30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\infin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Hi so when ever I try to run this code in visual code studio it won't work! The code itself has no problems what so ever, I have tried changing the token to see if that is the reason but it still isn't working. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Edit your question and remove your token. Then change your token on Discord. Your token is personal and should be kept a secret.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass a valid token to `client.run`, try using a new token with it. Also, in the future, make sure to remove your token from any snippets you share on this site, as anyone with your token can log in as your bot.

Comment: I just regenerated my token for my bot and replaced it but it is still giving me that same exact error message.

Comment: Did you save the file after replacing the token? Also, how are you getting the token? Make sure that you're copying the token from the Bot tab in the developer portal, and that you're not copying the client secret

Comment: uh yes I did, I think something is wrong with Visual Studio code itself, I just tried to run ```print("hi")``` and it is also giving me this huge error...

Comment: Try running it from your command prompt (you can hover over the file name in Visual Studio Code to see the directory it's saved in)

Comment: Just open a command prompt, use `cd <folder>` to go to the folder that the file's saved in, and use `python <filename>.py` to run it

Comment: oh wait I fixed it xD i did what you told me to ( saved the file ) and ran it and it worked. thank you!